# Setting state inside useEffect triggers infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

Im creating a custom autosave hook for my project that uses `react-hook-form`. Inside this custom hook I want to add two pieces of state, `isSaving` and `saveMessage`

The custom hook works fine until I change those states, triggering an infinite loop. I dont understand why this is happening since the states are not a dependency of the `useEffect`.

```js
    const { saveMessage } = useAutoSave(
        formVals,
        onSubmit,
        [formVals, rows, passengers],
        params
    );
```

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const useAutoSave = (formVals, onSubmit, dependencies, params) => {
    const [isSaving, setIsSaving] = useState(null);
    const [saveMessage, setSaveMessage] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        const submitFormValues = async () => {
            if (params) {
                setIsSaving(true);
                setSaveMessage("Saving...");
                console.log("formVasl", formVals);
                await onSubmit(formVals);
                setIsSaving(false);
                const currentDate = new Date().toLocaleString();
                setSaveMessage(`Saved ${currentDate}`);
                return;
            }
        };

        const timeoutId = setTimeout(submitFormValues, 500);

        return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    }, dependencies);

    return {
        isSaving,
        saveMessage,
    };
};
```

By removing the `setIsSaving` and the `setSaveMessage` the hook works as intended. I read multiple posts about this issue of state inside useEffect triggering infinite loop but in those cases the changed state was a part of the dependencies of `useEffect`, which is not in this case.

EDIT1:

Im adding `rows` and `passengers` to the dependencies because this values come from two tables that are related with the form but not inside it.

My `onSubmit`function:

```js
    const onSubmit = async (data) => {
        const crewIds = rows.map((row) => row.crew_id);
        const paxIds = passengers.map((row) => row.pax_id);

        const flight = {
            ...data,
            crew_ids: crewIds,
            etd_lt: data.etd_lt.getTime(),
            pax_ids: paxIds,
        };

        if (!params.id) {
            const res = await createFlight(flight);

            navigate(`/flights/${res.data._id}`);
        } else {
            await updateFlight(params.id, flight);
            // navigate("/");
        }
    };
```

`rows` and `passengers` are updated through an arrow function in a button, like so:

```
  <button
                            type="button"
                            className="hidden md:block bg-green-600 hover:bg-green-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded my-4"
                            onClick={() =>
                                setPassengers([
                                    ...passengers,
                                    {
                                        passportExp: new Date(0),
                                        dob: new Date(0),
                                        visaExp: new Date(0),
                                    },
                                ])
                            }
                        >
                            Add new
                        </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're passing unessicary dependencies to your use effect that could be causing constant re-renders - without seeing the code where your deps are being updated its hard to say what the issue is but it looks like your deps are causing side effects or if your onSubmit is like most submits then it causes a re-render of the component which will being 'new' values to your dependencies which will trigger use effect over and over.

Try using callbacks for your submit function to make sure it is not causing unintended re-draws:

```
const { saveMessage } = useAutoSave(
    formVals,
    useCallback(onSubmit, []), // Memoize onSubmit
    [formVals, rows, passengers, params]
);
```

```
import { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";

export const useAutoSave = (formVals, onSubmit, dependencies, params) => {
    const [isSaving, setIsSaving] = useState(null);
    const [saveMessage, setSaveMessage] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        const submitFormValues = async () => {
            if (params) {
                setIsSaving(true);
                setSaveMessage("Saving...");
                console.log("formVals", formVals);
                await onSubmit(formVals);
                setIsSaving(false);
                const currentDate = new Date().toLocaleString();
                setSaveMessage(`Saved ${currentDate}`);
                return;
            }
        };

        const timeoutId = setTimeout(submitFormValues, 500);

        return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    }, [formVals, ...dependencies]); // Include formVals explicitly and spread other dependencies...do you even need the other deps? this is on save and should not need all these extra deps 

    return {
        isSaving,
        saveMessage,
    };
};
```

Also I know its super basic but I added a console log so when you preform your form functions keep an eye on the console and see when/what is causing re-renders. It is even possible that one of your deps unintentionally changing or re-rendering (callback for functions and state for variables should fix this )

Comment: Thanks! I just added a bit more info and code for this. I tried your suggestions but its still infinite looping, everything works great until i add the state change inside submitFormValues. If i remove everything and i just leave "await onSubmit(formVals)" the behavior is the expected.